# Can't add 'cursor: pointer' hover with JSS in React Typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jss

I am trying to integrate a very simple hover effect (the cursor pointer browser standard behaviour) to start in a pre-existing React-Typescript project.

I've researched various ways to do this since React doesn't offer a way to do CSS hover styles out of the box with inline styling, and have settled on using the JSS.

In my `package.json` file in dependencies I have `"react-jss": "^7.0.2"` and `"jss-preset-default": "^3.0.0"`

In the relevant React-Typescript .tsx file I have `import jss from 'jss';`
and `import preset from 'jss-preset-default'`

To implement I have followed the example here: `https://github.com/cssinjs/jss` but I also have quite a bit of other code which I am inheriting from another developer in this file (which I hope is not conflicting in some way).

There is no error in the terminal or in the browser console. There is also no error in the editor's in-built React/typescript linter.

The only thing I can think is that it is something to do with my use of `className` in the JSX as strangely in the jss github doc they use as standard class in standard HTML.

Here's the full code below:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Link from '../../lib/support/Link';
import Grid from 'material-ui/Grid';
import ODPaper from '../ui/ODPaper';
import Typography from 'material-ui/Typography';
import {MakerPresenter} from '../../lib/presenters/MakerPresenter';
import {StyleRulesCallback, withStyles} from 'material-ui/styles';
import ODAvatar from '../ui/ODAvatar';
import jss from 'jss';
import preset from 'jss-preset-default'

jss.setup(preset())

const styleSheet: StyleRulesCallback = (theme: any) => ({
  item: {
    minheight: 65
  }
});

const bkgroundTxt = {
  backgroundColor: '#9b9b9b',
  color: '#fff',
  padding: '5px',
  textAlign: 'center'
}

const extraStyles = {
  customLink: {
    '&:hover': {
      cursor: 'pointer'
    }
  }
}

const {extraClasses} = jss.createStyleSheet(extraStyles).attach()

interface IProps {
  maker: MakerPresenter;
  distanceInKm?: number;
}

interface IStyles {
  item: string;
}

// const MakerItemHeaders =

const MakerListItem = ({maker, distanceInKm, classes}: IProps & {classes: IStyles}) =>

  // {MakerItemHeaders}

  <ODPaper>
    <Link as={maker.href} href={`/makers/show?id=${maker.id}`}>
      <Grid className="${extraClasses.customLink}" container align="center">

        <Grid item xs={2}>
          <Typography component="span">{maker.name}</Typography>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Typography>{maker.prettyAddress}</Typography>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={2}>
          <Typography>Jobs complete: {maker.numJobs}</Typography>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={2}>
          <Typography>QA issues: {maker.numQAIssues}</Typography>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={2}>
          <Typography style={bkgroundTxt} >{maker.onboardedStatus}</Typography>
        </Grid>

          <Grid item xs={3}>
            <Typography>Data Missing: {maker.dataMissing}</Typography>
          </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <Typography>
            { (typeof distanceInKm !== 'undefined') && `Distance (km): ${distanceInKm}`}
          </Typography>
        </Grid>

      </Grid>
    </Link>
  </ODPaper>;

export default withStyles<IProps>(styleSheet)(MakerListItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use JSS directly you just need this:

```
const {classes} = jss.createStyleSheet(extraStyles).attach()
```

If you use withStyles or reactJss, you don't need to create a style sheet manually, you just pass the styles object.

Comment: when you say pass the styles object - how exactly should I "call" extraStyles in the JSX?

Comment: I don't need this at all? - "${extraStyles.customLink}" as if I remove it and just do the standard style={customLin} it gets full of errors